# What is my yii regular expression?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I use this regular expression in the yii framework.But its not working.

```
 '<controller>-<action>-<pagekey:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/page'
```

And my URL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/site-page-contact-us
```

contact-us is a pagekey in the MySQL.
When i use this URL my pages error is:

```
Not found!
```

But when i use this URL,its working.

```
http://localhost:8080/site-page-about
```

My action code is:

```
public function actionPage($pagekey) {
    $pagekey = CHtml::encode($pagekey);
    if(!  $model = Pages::model()->findByAttributes(array('pagekey'=>$pagekey))){
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'Not found!');
    }
    $this->render('page', compact('model'));
}
```

Comment: show the action for contac-us, the exact view name

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: have you a controllerAction code for contac-us ..(probably in site controller)  then update the question adding this code .. and please provide the exact name fo your contact-us view ..

Comment: I can change pagekey to aboutus, But  i want use the code for any pages.

Comment: You are using Yii1 or Yii2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.
When i use this pattern its working.

```
 'site-page-<pagekey:.*>' => 'site/page'
```